# I want to edit a text in the existing power point slide using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for a way to edit a text on ppt using VBA,
as shown in the below image I have a requirement to edit the date where the date is coming from an excel.

[image]

I tried this but wasn't able to alter text.

```
ppTextbox.Table.Cell(1, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
ppTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "test"
```